# Second derivative of vector flows: if $g(t)=\varphi_{v_1}^t\circ \varphi_{v_2}^t-\varphi_{v_2}^t\circ \varphi_{v_1}^t$ then $g''(0)=-2[v_1,v_2](p)$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two vector fields on a manifold $M$, and let $g(t)=\varphi_{v_1}^t\circ \varphi_{v_2}^t-\varphi_{v_2}^t\circ \varphi_{v_1}^t$. I want to prove that
$$g''(0)=-2[v_1,v_2](p).$$
To do this, I tried writing
$$v_1(p)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\Big\vert_p \quad \text{and} \quad v_2(p)=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$$
Using that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\varphi^t_{v_i}=v_i(\varphi^t_{v_i})$ for $i=1,2$ I get that the first derivative is
$$g'(t)=v_1(\varphi_{v_1}^t(\varphi_{v_2}^t(p)))\cdot v_2(\varphi_{v_2}^t(p)))-v_2(\varphi_{v_2}^t(\varphi_{v_1}^t(p)))\cdot v_1(\varphi_{v_1}^t(p)))$$
This is my attempt for the second derivative:
$$g''(t)=
\frac{\partial}{\partial p}v_1(p)\Big|_{\varphi_{v_1}^t(\varphi_{v_2}^t(p))}\cdot v_2(\varphi_{v_2}^t(p)))+v_1(\varphi_{v_1}^t(\varphi_{v_2}^t(p)))\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial p}v_2(p)\Big|_{\varphi_{v_2}^t(p))}-
\frac{\partial}{\partial p}v_2(p)\Big|_{\varphi_{v_2}^t(\varphi_{v_1}^t(p))}\cdot v_1(\varphi_{v_1}^t(p)))-v_2(\varphi_{v_2}^t(\varphi_{v_1}^t(p)))\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial p}v_1(p)\Big|_{\varphi_{v_1}^t(p))}$$
However, as $\varphi^0_{v_i}(p)=p$ for $i=1,2$, I get that $g''(0)=0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the third time I've seen this question posted in the past week. What does the negative sign even mean in your definition of $g$?

Comment: Related to Ted Shifrin's comment: instead of a linear combination of flows, which does not make much sense on arbitrary manifolds, you probably want to take their commutator: $\phi^t_1\circ\phi^t_2\circ\phi^{-t}_1\circ\phi^{-t}_2$.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon nope, this is what my exercise says

Comment: @kubo is it possible that there is a mistake in the statement? Anyway, see this post for a very much related question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209452/derivatives-of-the-commutator-of-flows-or-what-are-those-higher-derivatives-do

Comment: Nevermind, there is a way to interpret this so that it makes sense. See this question, that almost has the answer you look for https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142486/261022